# What are the possible poles of the meromorphic function $G$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, meromorphic-functions

> > Consider the function $$F(z)=\int_{1}^{2} \frac {1} {(x-z)^2}dx,\ \mathrm {Im} (z) > 0.$$ Then there is a meromorphic function $G(z)$ on $\Bbb C$ which agrees with $F(z)$ when $\mathrm {Im} (z) > 0$, such that
> >
> > $1.$ $\ 1, \infty$ are poles of $G(z)$.
> >
> > $2.$ $\ 0,1,\infty$ are poles of $G(z)$.
> >
> > $3.$ $\ 1,2$ are poles of $G(z)$.
> >
> > $4.$ $\ 1,2$ are simple poles of $G(z)$.

If we evaluate $F$ we get $F(z)=\frac {1} {(1-z)(2-z)},\ \mathrm {Im} (z) > 0$. So if we define a function $G$ by $G(z)=\frac {1} {(1-z)(2-z)}$ then $G$ is analytic everywhere except for the simple poles at $1$ and $2$ and agrees with $F$ on $\mathrm {Im} (z) > 0$ since $\{z \in \Bbb C : \mathrm {Im} (z) > 0 \} \subset  \Bbb C \setminus \{1,2 \}$. So clearly $(3)$ and $(4)$ are the correct options. I think $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not correct but what is the reason behind that? I got stuck here. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Two meromorphic functions on $\mathbb C$ that agree on a nonempty open set are identically equal.  So there is only one possible $G$, and it satisfies (3) and (4) but not (1) and (2).

Comment: $(2)$ is clearly false. Since a function cannot have a pole and a zero at a same point. (In this case the point is the origin).

Comment: Where do I find the proof of the above theorem?

Comment: Who said anything about a zero?

Comment: As for the proof: essentially it's the fact that the complement of a discrete set in the complex plane is connected.

Comment: But it implies that $G$ is unique on $\Bbb C \setminus S$ where $S$ is the set of all poles of $f$ by identity theorem.

Comment: $G$ is defined on $\Bbb C \setminus S$ too. So this proves the theorem. But how can I prove the fact regarding connectedness of $\Bbb C \setminus S$ what you have stated in your last comment?

Comment: Given any two points $x, y$ in $\mathbb C \backslash S$, consider paths from $x$ to $y$ consisting of a segment of length $r$ in some fixed direction not parallel to $y-x$ followed by a straight line segment.  For sufficiently small $r > 0$, this is in $\mathbb C \backslash S$.